# Numpy transpose usage

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Can't inderstand why numpy doesn't transpose matrix.

This doesn't work:

```
w=2
h=3
rc= np.array([[0,0,1],[0,h,1],[w,h,1],[w,0,1]])

array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [2, 0, 1]])

rc[0].T

array([0, 0, 1])
```

but this works:

```
v_x= np.array([[0,1,2,3]])
v_x.T
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rc[0] is not an 1x3 matrix, it's rather a vector of 3 items:

```
>>> rc[0].shape
(3,)
```

Fix its shape if you want to transpose it:

```
>>> np.reshape(rc[0], (1,3)).T
array([[0],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

Comment: This is also the difference between `np.array([0,1,2,3])` (which is its own transpose) and `np.array([[0,1,2,3]])` (which, as noted in the OP, transposes into a 4x1 matrix).

Answer (score 2):

One of the first things I ask when confronted with a problem like this is: what's the shape?

```
In [14]: rc.shape
Out[14]: (4, 3)

In [15]: rc[0].shape
Out[15]: (3,)
```

Indexing has selected a row, and reduced the number of dimensions.

But if I index with a list (or array), the result is 2d

```
In [16]: rc[[0]].shape
Out[16]: (1, 3)
In [19]: v_x.shape
Out[19]: (1, 4)
```

There are other ways of getting that shape, or even the target `(3,1)`.

```
rc[0].reshape(1,-1) # -1 stands in for the known 3
rc[0][np.newaxis,:] # useful when constructing outer products

rc[0].reshape(-1,1) # transposed
rc[0][:,np.newaxis]
```

`np.matrix` is a subclass of `np.array` that is always 2d (even after indexing with a scalar)

```
rcm = np.matrix(rc)
rcm[0] # (1,3)
rcm[0].T # (3,1)
```

`np.matrix` can ease the transition if you are coming to `numpy` from MATLAB, especially the older versions where everything was a 2d matrix.  For others it is probably better to become familiar with `ndarray`, and use `matrix` only if it adds some functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Transpose in fact works, but not as you expected, [see docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

> By default, **reverse** the dimensions

So, as your array is 1d, reverse do nothing with its shape:

```
>>> np.array([0,0,1]).T.shape
(3,)
```

You can add more dimensions with `reshape`:

```
>>> np.array([0,0,1]).reshape(-1,1,1).shape
(3, 1, 1)
```

Now, nontrivial shape can be reversed:

```
>>> np.array([0,0,1]).reshape(-1,1,1).T.shape
(1, 1, 3)
```